# How can I write this line of code in MATLAB (currently R)?

Tags: r, matlab

How can I write this line of code in MATLAB (currently R)?

```
vcov_beta_hat <- c(sigma2_hat) * solve(t(X) %*% X)
```

My attempt is,

```
vcov_beta_hat = [sigma2_hat.*((X'*X))];
```

However I am struggling on what the 'c' is doing in the r code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whilst the above answer addresses that the solve is the something missing in your matlab code, solve can mean a number of different things in R,

If there is no comma in the equation its not solving anything and is actually taking the inverse,

Inverse of A, MATLAB: inv(A) R: solve(A)

Therefore, `vcov_beta_hat = [sigma2_hat.*inv((X'*X))];`

Comment: Just a note for efficiency. First the square brackets aren't needed, actually they make it slower. Also, as probably noted by the MATLAB editor, you should not use `*inv(A)` but `mrdivide`

Answer (score -2):

The `c(a,b,c)` denote a vector in R. In Matlab, you would write

```
vec = [a b c];
```

Also, you need to find the equivalent of the R-`solve()` function. So far, your matlab code just mutliplies X' with X and does not solve the system of equations.

[linsolve](https://de.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/linsolve.html) should be a good starting point.

Comment: Thanks for having an attempt at the answer. Specifically how would the linsolve work here, I am struggling when trying to use it?